# How to iterate over this dataframe with fixed values and unique conditions corresponding to the 1st trial?

Tags: r

Hello I have such a dataframe as this:

[image]

This is a dataframe of some of my experimental measurements of various gases such as CO2 and N2 as they migrate from tank A to tank B as I open and close a valve and the gas moves down a pressure gradient. My objective is to measure the comprehensibility of these gases as a function of pressure.

1. Replicate: Each time I setup the apparatus.
2. Trial: Each unique measurement
3. Gas: CO2, N2, etc ...
4. R = 8.3145 * 10^(-2) liter * bar / (mole * K)
5. Each unique Pressure_B is circled in the spreadsheet.

   My Goal:

**I wish to calculate the moles of the gas in tank B which corresponds to column "n_subB" in the dataframe.**

I have calculated these values in in Excel with careful dragging and dropping and then fixing the initial pressures for each unique replicate when the trial is 1. But I think it's pretty error-prone so I would like to code the calculations for column n_subB

The formula that I am using to calculate n_sub is this:

**n_subB = [ Pressure<sub>b</sub> - (Pressure<sub>b</sub>)<sub>initial</sub> ] * V<sub>b</sub> / (R * T)**

Therefore the number of moles of B at a certain pressure is that current pressure minus the initial pressure (**corresponding to trial 1**) times the volume in tank B all over (R * T).

What I wish to do is iterate over this dataframe row by row:

for each unique **Replicate** or if the **Gas** is different,
calculate **n_subB** for that current row by calculating the the current Pressure_B minus the initial Pressure_B times the V_sub_B all over (R * Temperature)

Some example calculations:

For Replicate 1, Trial 8 of CO2 gas:

**n_subB = [ -0.914 - (-0.958) ] * 21.17 / (0.083145 * 297.15) = 0.0377
where the initial Pressure_B is -0.958 bars.**

But the calculation is different for all the trials of Replicate 2 of gas CO2

For trial 5

**n_subB = [-0.93 -(-0.955)] * 21.17 all over (0.083145 * 297.15) = 0.0214 moles,
where the initial Pressure_B = -0.955 bars.**

That initial pressure will stay the same up to trial 15, until we get the new gas N2, and then the initial pressure changes again.

Now that I think about it, I just need to alternate the initial pressure for each unique trial 1. I've circled each of the unique pressures in my spreadsheet.

How do you suggest I create column n_subB in R?
I'm very perplexed by this.

Thanks!

This is what I get when I dput my dataframe:

```
structure(list(Replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), Trial = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L), Gas = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CO2", "N2"), class = "factor"), Pressure_A = c(12.8, 
11.7, 10.8, 9.7, 8.7, 7.7, 6.7, 5.7, 4.7, 3.7, 2.7, 1.7, 0.7, 
0, 13.7, 12.7, 11.8, 10.7, 9.8, 8.7, 7.7, 6.7, 5.7, 4.7, 3.7, 
2.7, 1.7, 0.7, 0, 11.9, 10.7, 9.6, 8.7, 7.7, 6.7, 5.7, 4.7, 3.7, 
2.7, 1.6, 0.7, 0), Pressure_B = c(-0.958, -0.957, -0.946, -0.939, 
-0.933, -0.926, -0.92, -0.914, -0.908, -0.902, -0.896, -0.89, 
-0.884, -0.879, -0.955, -0.949, -0.943, -0.936, -0.93, -0.923, 
-0.917, -0.91, -0.904, -0.898, -0.892, -0.886, -0.88, -0.874, 
-0.866, -0.951, -0.945, -0.939, -0.934, -0.927, -0.922, -0.916, 
-0.911, -0.905, -0.899, -0.893, -0.888, -0.883), V_sub_B = c(21.17, 
21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 
21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 
21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 
21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 
21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17, 21.17), R = c(0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 
0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 
0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 
0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 
0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 
0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831, 0.0831), Temperature = c(297.15, 
297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 
297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 
297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 
297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 
297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 297.15, 
297.15)), .Names = c("Replicate", "Trial", "Gas", "Pressure_A", 
"Pressure_B", "V_sub_B", "R", "Temperature"), row.names = c(NA, 
42L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've been thinking about doing something like this:

```
# Iterate over the dataframe in a loop. 
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  # This is each row:
  r <- df[i, ]
  
  # while gas or replicate is unique
  #{
  initial_P_subB = NULL
     if(r$Trial == 1)
     {
       initial_P_subB = r$Pressure_B
     }
      n_subB = (r$Pressure_B - initial_P_subB) / (r$R * r$Temperature)
      
      # Then cbind or rbind (n_subB) to dataframe. 
  
  #}
  
}
```

But I can't figure out how to alternate the special conditions.

Comment: Please `dput` your dataframe and share as part of question.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: >dput(your_dataframe) on command line and share output.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean.  I have dput() my dataframe.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far and why it failed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look for solution in couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    group_by(Gas, Replicate) %>%
    mutate(n_subB = ((Pressure_B-first(Pressure_B))*V_sub_B)/(R*Temperature))
```

#### Result

I've printed just the identifying columns and `n_subB` for the first 16 rows (enough to see it works after `Replicate` increments):

```
# A tibble: 42 x 4
# Groups:   Gas, Replicate [3]
   Replicate Trial    Gas       n_subB
       <int> <int> <fctr>        <dbl>
 1         1     1    CO2 0.0000000000
 2         1     2    CO2 0.0008573223
 3         1     3    CO2 0.0102878671
 4         1     4    CO2 0.0162891229
 5         1     5    CO2 0.0214330565
 6         1     6    CO2 0.0274343123
 7         1     7    CO2 0.0325782458
 8         1     8    CO2 0.0377221794
 9         1     9    CO2 0.0428661130
10         1    10    CO2 0.0480100465
11         1    11    CO2 0.0531539801
12         1    12    CO2 0.0582979136
13         1    13    CO2 0.0634418472
14         1    14    CO2 0.0677284585
15         2     1    CO2 0.0000000000
16         2     2    CO2 0.0051439336
```

#### Explanation

If you haven't been introduced to `dplyr`, I'd suggest reading up on it, starting with the [introductory vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html). It can make data wrangling tasks much easier (though I wouldn't necessarily say it always does).

To explain this bit of code, you mostly need to know about `%>%`, `group_by()`, `mutate()`, and `first()`. The pipe operator (originally from `magrittr`) `%>%` passes the result of the operation on the left hand side to the function on the right hand side. `group_by()` groups the data by variables given as arguments, so that the functions in later piped operations are applied to the data *by group*. The `first(x)` function would then take the first observation of `x` in a particular group. Finally, in `dplyr` syntax, `mutate()` is one way to define a new variable.

Comment: Woah! There's a first() function! That makes indexing so much easier, and what magic is %>% doing? How do you not need a loop?

Comment: @xyz123 I'll edit the answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @xyz123 No problem; glad it helped! Some explanation is up now; if the solution solved your issue, don't forget to accept the answer (From [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235): Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.")

Comment: Thank you so much! I've had to do so much more grouping and adjusting initial and final conditions, and your solution just works for all cases!